# Share a news from a sharepoint intranet to linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api, sharepoint-online

I am trying to figure a way to share a news from an intranet sharepoint online (classic) site to a personal linkedin account, without using a linkedin connector for security reasons.

My first guess would be to first export this news to a publicly accessible location then find a way to share it.

Anyone does that before or could suggest something?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could enable external sharing in SharePoint Online, thus you could share the news from the SharePoint site to external users(linkedin account).

The below articles would help you enable external sharing in SharePoint Online:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/external-sharing-overview
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off